# Google Apps Script scrape data from website with OAuth and recaptcha

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0, recaptcha

### Background:

I want to scrape data from a website by "google apps script" for personal use.
The data is from a member page which means i have to set a username and password to payload and pass the cookies to member page. This worked before the website upgraded.

Below is the code i used before:

```
      var url = "https://ww2.metroplex.com.hk/en/member/login";
      var formData = {
        'username': userEmail,
        'password': userPW
      };
      var options = {
        "method": "post",
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData),
        "followRedirects": false,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

      var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location']; 

      //**************Member Page (after login)******************
      var url = "https://ww2.metroplex.com.hk/en/member/login/profile";
      if (redirectUrl != null){
        url = redirectUrl;
      }

      var cookie_string = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
      var cookie = [{}];
      for (var i = 0; i < cookie_string.length; i++) {
        cookie[i] = cookie_string[i].split( ';' )[0];
      };

      cookie = cookie.join(';');
      var dataHeaders = {
        'Cookie': cookie
      };


      options = {
        "method": "get",
        "headers": dataHeaders
      };

      var dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var dataResponseCode = response.getResponseCode();  

      var html_text = dataResponse.getContentText();

      var table_array = html_text.split("Member Summary");
```

i want to get member information (Member Summary) like below:
[image: Expected information]

The website currently upgraded and the above method did not work.

The "table_array" should be returned 2 array splitted by value "Member Summary", but currently the value is same as html_text 
[image: return table_array value]

I trace the network by Chrome and i see there are few things that might need to pass during log-in

1. access token
2. authorization
3. recaptcha

I am not sure whether the recaptcha is required.

I don't know how to get it work. If anyone experiences this kind of website and can program it to log-in and scrape data. Please feel free to discuss

### Below is the website i want to access:

https://ww2.metroplex.com.hk/en/movie/highlight

You can use temporary email for registration:

https://ww2.metroplex.com.hk/en/member/freeregister

and the trace network I preformed:

the access token when you go to the website
[image: the access token when you go to the website[1]]

there is an oauth authorization
[image: there is an oauth authorization[2]]

google recaptcha
[image: google recaptcha[3]]

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample of the Apps Script script you are using the see where the issue might be and which sort of Apps Script methods are you using? Also, you basically want to make a get request to this site, am I right? What do you exactly want to retrieve from the site? Are you using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for this?

Comment: hi Meteo, i add the code in the content.
I just want to get request and retrieve data after login to the website

Comment: Hi ! I have tried to reproduce your issue and I was successfully able to use my credentials to get authorised and have the HTML returned. What is the response you are getting when running your script?

Comment: hi Meteo, i have update the content clearly for what i would expect. In the last line of the code, i use the split("Member Summary") for scrape only member information, but the array return HTML with no split (it means it cannot successfully login by user).  Can you?  I am wonder if i need to pass other parameter/value (authorization/access token) during the second UrlFetchApp.fetch

Comment: I can´t either. This seems to be a security measure the website is taking in the right (in the right direction to avoid attacks or the use of bots). They are probably now using an access token and authorization way of login as you mentioned and recaptcha is just for ensuring humans are the ones logging in. The best way to workaround this is to use their API to access to your details if they have one.

Comment: Is there any way to find their API url? As i find a OAuth2.0 library provided in google but to use it, it need to provide the API and token url